# How can I show that $x$ and $y $ must have the same length where $ x+y $ and $x-y $ are non-zero vectors and perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> **Problem:** Let $x$ and $y$ be non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> (a) Suppose that $\|x+y\|=\|x−y\|$. Show that $x$ and $y$ must be perpendicular.
> (b) Suppose that $x+y$ and $x−y$ are non-zero and perpendicular. Show that $x$
> and $y$ must have the same length.

**Attempt**:

(a)\begin{align*}\|x+y\|^2 & =\|x-y\|^2 \\
(x+y)\cdot (x+y) & =(x-y)\cdot (x-y) \\
\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2x\cdot y & =\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2x\cdot y \\
2x\cdot y & =-2x\cdot y \\
x\cdot y & =0.
\end{align*}(b)\begin{align*}(x+y)\cdot (x-y) & =0 \\
\|x\|^2-x\cdot y+x\cdot y-\|y\|^2 & =0 \\
\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2 & =0.
\end{align*}Are these attempts correct?

**EDITED**

Comment: Part (a) is good, except I would write the second line $$(x+y) \cdot (x+y) = (x-y) \cdot (x-y)$$ to keep it clear those are vector dot products.

Comment: As emacs points out, (a) is busted $-$ if $x+y=x-y$, then $y=0$. Are you sure it's not "Suppose that $||x+y|| = ||x-y||$"?

Comment: "*Suppose that x + y = x − y*" $\,$ You must mean $\|x+y\|=\|x-y\|$. The geometric intuition is that a parallelogram a) with equal diagonals is a rectangle, b) with orthogonal diagonals is a rhombus.

Comment: @dxiv You are right, I wrote it wrong. I have corrected it now, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @TonyK I have corrected the problem, I wrote it wrong.

Comment: @aschepler You have a point, thank you! I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is fine, well done.

For b) you're given $\mathbb{x+y}$ and $\mathbb{x-y}$ are perpendicular, which implies $\mathbb{(x+y)} \cdot \mathbb{(x-y)} = 0$

Now expand and apply the distributive and commutative properties of the dot product. Your end goal is to reach $|\mathbb x| = |\mathbb y|$

Comment: what about now? Did I do well?

Comment: @Sampaguita Yes, quite alright. Although at an elementary level I would show more steps like starting with x.x then only writing |x|^2 in the next step. Also taking care to write x.y and y.x in the correct order in your expansion then explicitly rearranging them both to x.y by invoking commutativity in the next step, before mutually cancelling them out. Remember, commutativity is an important property of the dot product but (for example) the cross product is *not* commutative, so you must show you're not just assuming it's all "ordinary" algebra. (continued)

Comment: (continued) Finally, end with the line |x| = |y|. Since taking square roots of both sides is justified by the fact that magnitudes are non-negative. I would expect a careful student to spell all these out. That's my advice.

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from where you got the starting relations.  That $x+y$ and $x-y$ are perpendicular means that
$$(x+y)\cdot(x-y) = 0 \tag 1$$
and you can start reasoning from there:

$$
0 \stackrel{(1)}= (x+y)\cdot(x-y) = x^2 +yx - xy -y^2 = \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2
$$

Thus $\|x\|^2 = \|y\|^2$ and taking square root yields $\|x\| = \|y\|$ which means that $x$ and $y$ have same length.

> Let $x$ and $y$ be non-zero vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.  Suppose that $x + y = x − y$. Show that $x$ and $y$ must be perpendicular.

Subtracting $x$ yields $y = -y$ and hence $y=0$ which violates the precondition that $y\neq0$.

Comment: I wrote the problem wrong, but I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

$a)$ Using [polarization identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

$4\langle x, y\rangle =\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2=0$

$\langle x, y\rangle =x\cdot y=0$

---

$b)$ Again using polarization identity

$\begin{align}4\langle x+y, x-y\rangle &=\|(x+y)+(x-y)\|^2-\|(x+y)-(x-y)\|^2\\&=4(\|x\|^2 -\|y\|^2)\end{align}$

Given $\langle x+y, x-y\rangle=0$ implies $\|x\|=\|y\|$